# SQL Server 2000 error handling

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a custom function in SQL which I want to return value NULL if it reports an error without breaking or stoping the procedure using this function.

How can I do that?

I know that the error handling should be done inside the function it self but what should I write in it?

example:
Procedure name is PROC
, Function Name is FUNC

code:

```
create dbo.PROC
AS
 select column1, column2, FUNC(column3) as funccolumn
from table1
do somthing else
GO
```

Comment: SQL Server 2000 has no TRY/CATCH so you cannot "handle" the errors, you can only prevent them. See also http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#UDF. Can you post the code of your UDF? What kinds of errors do you expect? (a) missing tables/columns (b) arithmetic overflow, division by zero, etc (c) hardware errors, disk full, etc (d) violation of constraints in table variables defined in the function (e) other types of errors?

Comment: the error expected is when I use the function on a varchar type while its designed for float or int, just that, so the procedure creates a table one column from it uses this function but when it passes a value that contains letters it stops the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the value you are going to pass to the function is a number:

```
    drop procedure sp_test
    go
    drop function fn_test
    go
    drop table t_test
    go

    create table t_test (id int, name varchar(255))
    go
    insert into t_test values(1,'coco')
    insert into t_test values(2,'cucu')
    insert into t_test values(2,'10')
    insert into t_test values(2,'10.5')
    go

    create function fn_test(@p decimal(18,6)) returns int
    as
    begin

            return @p * 10

    end
    go

    create procedure sp_test
    as
    begin

            select id, name, 
                /* when is a number you call the function */
                case when isnumeric(name)<>0 then dbo.fn_test(name) 
                /* if isn't a number you return NULL */
                else null end as call_to_fn_test 
            from t_test

    end
    go

    sp_test
```